# Multiple lines in a single row of hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
9,Time :
  Cost : Red pending agreement with MPP TBC
  Scope : This novelty puts strong requirement on navigation system;
```

if we do not modify the navigation system as it is today expected, the availability of this novelty will be close to zero (in non SBAS area).

```
10,prabha:
   lakesh
11,chandra
```

This is my CSV file data. I want to load this file into hive table . but the result should be like entire data of 2nd column will be in singe column. means it will inserted as same as in file in 2nd column of table. i got null values in new line .

Comment: Not able to get clearly your explanation about the problem, It would be great if you explain a bit clearly. What i think the problem here will be your column and row separator which you are defining. Please ensure that any field doesn't contain any extra comma while using csv file input.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple lines in a single row of hive table is easy to do since Hive does support structured data.

I'm not sure the data structures used in this example are what do you really need, but this is how to do what do you want:

```
create table test ( id int, data array<String> );
-- this is required to insert the data into the test table
create table dummy ( it int );
insert into dummy values (1);
insert into test select 10 , array("prabba:","lakes") from dummy;
insert into test select 11, array("chandra") from dummy;

select * from test;
```

Now, as you can see, the 2nd column has two lines in the same row.

```
0: jdbc:hive2://quickstart:10000/default> select * from test; 
+----------+----------------------+--+
| test.id  |      test.data       |
+----------+----------------------+--+
| 10       | ["prabba:","lakes"]  |
| 11       | ["chandra"]          |
+----------+----------------------+--+
```

Comment: Yes. I know that. But in my case is the data should be in array like no of lines example 3 lines paragraph .  so I need to print  that paragraph in single field.

Comment: when i am running select select statement i got this output. I dont need null here.                                                                                                 9       ["Time :"]
NULL    NULL
NULL    [" the availability of this novelty will be close to zero (in non SBAS area)."]                               
10      ["prabha:"]                                                                    
NULL    NULL
11      ["chandra"]